# Increase time of Django Sessions

Tags: python, django

I am working on a website in django framework .There is table in the DB as django_sessions which is a default table in the DB.
The session created is for 15 days once a user log in . How can I change it to more no of days?
Do i need to tweek the core files for that ,Because I strictly follow the policy not to touch the core files ,,for any sort of updates in the future .
[image]

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.setdefault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is driven by a setting called `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`

Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age)

If you want to set it to 18 days , in your settings file,

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 18 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: Thanks a lot boss .. But where can I find the code .. in the django core files ?

Comment: no .. all you have to do is in your settings.py file, add this setting. by default, it is set to 2 weeks - by setting this property, you would be overriding that to 18 days, or whatever value you set it to

Comment: It worked but still I can see some sessions created for 2 weeks .. ,Theses sessions are created at the time of login I think If am not wrong .

Comment: Yes! As per my thinking session will get active after you logged in and not before. So 2 week is default value for SESSION_COOKIE_AGE to it gets active by default. Correct me if i am wrong... thanks

Comment: This is working fine , No issue at all . It just overwrite the default value for 2 weeks .

Answer (score 1):

Default SESSION_COOKIE_AGE is 1209600 that is 2 week in seconds.

Take a look at the session middleware and its settings here is the link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#topics-http-sessions

and also visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/#session-cookie-age
link and it will provide all the session information that you required.

As said my @karthikr you can set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 18 * 24 * 60 * 60`

And if there is any case like a website that requires us to log a user out after N minutes of inactivity. At this time you can use the same settings

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE
Default: 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)
The age of session cookies, in seconds.

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST
Default: False
```

Whether to save the session data on every request. If this setting is False (default), then the session data will only be saved if it has been modified. In short, if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted.